# Outlook2003 doesn't work with Exchange2010 like it does with Exchange2003

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010

Our Outlook Addin gets no events anymore since we switched from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010. Is there a site that explains the facts behind the scenes?

update per 2010-03-18:

Since there are no relevant info's in this thread  yet, i refine my question as follows:

- What are the key-words to get some relevant matches in a google-search?
- Is there anybody how can explain the reason for microsoft to change the protocoll?

Comment: Is this a custom Outlook Addin?  What is it trying to do?  How does it interact with the server?

Comment: @Paul Cunningham: This Addin detects (under Exchange2003 by event, under Exchange2010 there are no events anymore) any changes in calendar, tasks e.g. every Folder and put a entry in a interface-table on sql-server via odbc-connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange 2010 requires, by default, RPC encryption to be enabled and by default this is disabled in Outlook 2003. You can either disable the requirement for encryption or enable it on you clients. Full details on this and how to resolve it can be found in [this KB articl](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006508)e.

Comment: Just to clarify, Exchange 2010 RTM has the RPC encryption requirement enabled by default, but if you deployed straight to Exchange 2010 SP1 it does not have that requirement.

Comment: As i understand this materia, this is off-topic: Outlook2003 works in this particular case, i dont't know which settings are mandatory for that but this doesn't matter.